# Writing a Compiler - .reloc section of the COFF

Tags: c#, .net, compiler

I'm looking for a little bit of direction in writing a compiler.  I've written in `Common Intermediate Language`, `C#`, and various other .NET languages; I've written my own Metadata Parser and now I'm trying to understand the various aspects of the Portable Executable (`PE`) layout.  One thing that somewhat befuddles me is the `.reloc` section.

I have the Relocs parsing (or at least I think I do? :) and I wanted to know, within .NET libraries they usually have a single Reloc block with a single HighLow (`IMAGE_REL_BASED_HIGHLOW`, or just `3`) reloc at a given offset that changes.  When I go to writing my own PE Header and COFF sections, how do I calculate the `Relative Virtual Address` of the block, and the `Offset` (lower 12 bits) on the `TypeOffset` entry that follows that block header?

I'm currently using the pecoff_v83.docx (**Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification Revision 8.3**) from Microsoft's website, but I think there's a step I'm missing out on.

I'll link a relevant post: [How are PE Base Relocations build up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436668/how-are-pe-base-relocations-build-up)

^ That helped me parse the Reloc entries, but **parsing** them and **generating** the data that goes into them are different questions.

Comment: For now, since it had been three-four years since I last worked with the PE Header work, I will go back and reevaluate their structure (with the spec) in hopes it will shed some light on the Reloc section, perhaps there's a commonality between them I'm not seeing.

Comment: A compiler targeting the .NET Framework (Common Language Infrastructure, ECMA-335.)

Comment: I think it's a fascinating idea.  There are now THREE open source SETS of C# compilers. There's classic mono. There's the DNX stuff, and then there's ROSLYN.  I would think you will find more "concrete documentation" on COFF-output-generation in these concrete implementations than anywhere in any documentation.  Best of luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32416/discussion-between-alexander-morou-and-warren-p).

Comment: @Warren P, May I ask what the name of the DNX C# compiler is? Thank you.

Comment: It is all run from within a single tool, called dnx, which includes a compilation system, and a runtime system.   You type a command line `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1` to set up your path. Then you type `dnx web` or `dnx run` to compile and run in the current folder.  

https://github.com/aspnet/dnx

Answer (score 2):

> ... how do I calculate the `Relative Virtual Address` of the block, and the Offset (lower 12 bits) on the `Type` `Offset` entry that follows that block header?

Microsoft - [PE Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#the-reloc-section-image-only) (05/30/2018):

> "**Base Relocation Block**

> Each base relocation block starts with the following structure:

> Offset      Size      Field      Description

> ---

0                4           RVA      The image base plus the page RVA is added to each   offset to create the VA where the base relocation must be applied.

> 4               4            BS         The total number of bytes in the base relocation
> block, including the Page RVA and Block Size fields and the Type/Offset fields that follow.

> 

> The Block Size field is then followed by any number of Type or Offset field entries. Each entry is a WORD (2 bytes) and has the following structure:

> Offset      Size      Field      Description

> ---

0               4b         Type      Stored in the high 4 bits of the WORD, a value that indicates the type of base relocation to be applied. For more information, see [Base Relocation Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#base-relocation-types).

> 0              12b        Type      Stored in the remaining 12 bits of the WORD, an offset from the starting address that was specified in the Page RVA field for the block. This offset specifies where the base relocation is to be applied.

> ...

> ".

Example code is in [BinUtils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

You can find testing code in [`binutils/ld/testsuite/ld-cygwin`](https://github.com/zeha/xc32/tree/e6c11663df24ad6124cb363fb23258d975b212c8/pic32m-source/src48x/binutils/ld/testsuite/ld-cygwin).